# How to connect to a running mitmproxy wsgi-flask-app on Ubuntu

Tags: mitmproxy

I am working with the example here:
https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/addons/wsgi-flask-app.py

I have tried using the **upstream** means to connect to it like

> mitmproxy --mode upstream:http://127.0.0.1:2108@8000 -s wsgi-flask-app.py

but it didn't work. I also tried setting my hosts file

> sudo nano /etc/hosts

I want to know what one will configure to be able to hit the stated route through mitmproxy. Do note that the http://127.0.0.1:2108 is served through

> python3 -m http.server 2108

Comment: I am sorry but I only understand the title and the first paragraph. The other parts don't fit into your question, so I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Robert I described how I ran the script I showed the link. Inside the script there are information on being able to hit a domain being served.

The issue I am having is being able to hit that domain. I wanted to know what one will set, if possible, to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

The [Mitmproxy WSGI sample script add-on](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/addons/wsgi-flask-app.py) is pretty simple, it provides a virtual host on which you can implement custom routes using Flask.

You can run mitmproxy with this add-on you can simply use mitmproxy/mitmdump/mitmweb using the following arguments:

```
mitmdump -s wsgi-flask-app.py
```

This starts mitmproxy in regular proxy mode on port 8080. As a next step you have to use a HTTP client or web browser that is configured to use mitmproxy as http proxy (in this example the mitmproxy proxy URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8080`). Use the http client to request the url `http://example.com` on port 80.
I use curl command-line tool but any other http client works as well:

```
curl --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080" http://example.com:80/
```

or without port (http uses implicit port 80):

```
curl --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080" http://example.com/
```

Executing this command will return `Hello World!` from the `hello_world()` function in `wsgi-flask-app.py`

Comment: Wow! It didn't even cross my mind to try it using the proxy method. I appreciate your help. It worked.